# Web enabled .EXE

Tags: java, activex, client, exe, hta

Is it possible for a website to automatically run an external .exe file upon visiting? That is, an .exe file that is not already on the client file system. If so how is this possible? Also, i've read about the use of HTA files or ActiveX components or Java in this process. Is it possible for a java applet to write code to a client's file system upon visiting a website? I understand this is a serious security concern, please enlighten me further. Thank you.

Comment: In theory, no. In practice, yes. Read up on drive-by downloads: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Drive-by_download

Comment: tell me the url of your site... just so I NEVER go there :)

Answer (score 2):

it's possible, the app (exe or applet) must be signed and granted permission by the user in order to run. even still the user's security policy may deny it, but it's possible..

java trusted applet info:

http://www-personal.umich.edu/~lsiden/tutorials/signed-applet/signed-applet.html

signed activex control:

http://dedjo.blogspot.com/2007/07/creating-exposing-and-signing-activex.html

Answer (score 0):

It really sounds like what you need is a browser plugin;

check out FireBreath: http://firebreath.googlecode.com

it will allow you to create a c++ plugin that will run on almost any windows browser, and you can do whatever you need with it.

Note that the user will have to install the plugin/ActiveX control first, and that you need to be very careful with security considerations (i.e. make sure nobody can run arbitrary code on the remote computer)